# How to check if a target of an LLVM AllocaInst is a function pointer

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

`%pointer = alloca void (i32)*, align 8`
How to check if %pointer is a function pointer?Can I get the parameter list of the function pointer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let Create a function that check if an `Alloca Instruction Type` is a function pointer.

```
bool  isFunctionPointerType(Type *type){
      // Check the type here
     if(PointerType *pointerType=dyn_cast<PointerType>(type)){
        return isFunctionPointerType(pointerType->getElementType());
     }
        //Exit Condition
        else if(type->isFunctionTy()){
        return  true;
        }
       return false;
  }
```

In your `runOnModule`/`runOnFunction` Pass

```
if(AllocaInst *allocaInst=dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(inst)){
     if(isFunctionPointerType(allocaInst->getType())){
     errs()<<"Funtion Pointer Type\n";
     }
  }
```

The above pass are tested on the following `source.c` code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(int a)
{
    printf("Value of a is %d\n", a);
}

int main()
{

    void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &fun;

    (*fun_ptr)(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Corresponding LLVM Bitcode without any optimization

```
entry:
%retval = alloca i32, align 4
%fun_ptr = alloca void (i32)*, align 8
store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata void (i32)** %fun_ptr, metadata !11,
... metadata !15), !dbg !16
store void (i32)* @_Z3funi, void (i32)** %fun_ptr, align 8, !dbg !16
%0 = load void (i32)*, void (i32)** %fun_ptr, align 8, !dbg !17
call void %0(i32 10), !dbg !18
ret i32 0, !dbg !19
```

Successfully detect `func_ptr` as a function pointer.

Note that the code use `recursion` to find the type `recursively`

Another way is to track the used of `func_ptr` using `def-use` chain in LLVM, ie by tracking the `StoreInst` and check if the source operand is a pointer to function : haven't try yet.

Hope this helps...
If it help please mark it as correct solution or upvote.. Thanks..

Comment: Right, except `isPointerTy()` should be `isFunctionTy()`.